# scrolling a panel with custom drawn controls

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, draw

I have a panel that has a collection of custom drawn controls. I know how to programmically scroll the panel but the problem is how the controls draw when scrolling. when scrolling right the control shows as normal but when scrolling left it is not looking correctly. This just the start of the complete application so I just have some basic testing in place right now. Need to find a way for the control to draw correctly when scrolling.

Form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Panel pn;
    private int location = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pn = new Panel()
        {
            Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 20,
            Height = 120,
            BackColor = Color.Black,
            Left = 5,
            Top = 20
        };
        pn.AutoScroll = false;
        pn.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 100;
        pn.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 100;
        pn.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
        pn.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        pn.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
        pn.AutoScroll = true;
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(keyPress);
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
        {
            CustomControl1 cc = null;
            if (i % 2 != 0)
                cc = new CustomControl1()
                {
                    isOdd = true,
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 100,
                    Left = (100*i)+5,
                    Top = 0
                };
            else
                cc = new CustomControl1()
                {
                    isOdd = false,
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 100,
                    Left = (100 * i) + 5,
                    Top = 0
                };
            pn.Controls.Add(cc);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(pn);
    }
    private void keyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                if(location - 20 >0)
                {
                    location -= 20;
                    pn.HorizontalScroll.Value = location;
                }
                else
                {
                    location = 0;
                    pn.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(location, 0);
                }
                break;
            case Keys.D:
                if(location +20 < pn.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    location += 20;
                    pn.HorizontalScroll.Value = location;
                }
                else
                {
                    location = pn.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
                    pn.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(location, 0);
                }
                break;
        }
        foreach(Control c in pn.Controls)
        {
            c.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Control Code:

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public bool isOdd { get; set; }
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics gr = pe.Graphics;
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pe.ClipRectangle.X,pe.ClipRectangle.Y,100,100);
        Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        if (isOdd)
            br = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        gr.FillEllipse(br, rc);
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(pe);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: also forgot to mention to scroll left is "A" and to scroll right is "D"

Comment: `but when scrolling left it is not looking correctly`  What does not correctly look like?

Comment: it cuts the control in half by showing the next control overtop of it. I want it to  display showing off the edge of the panel. Its hard to explain unless you test the code and see it for your self

Comment: I did test it.  How am I supposed to know what you are trying to achieve?  You didn't put that in your question.

Comment: Just added a picture to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't clip your drawing:

```
//Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pe.ClipRectangle.X, pe.ClipRectangle.Y, 100, 100);
Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
```